# Is it safe to use this online tool to generate my Windows Answer File?

Tags: windows

I found a [Tool to generate an unattended Windows Answer File for Windows Installation](http://windowsafg.no-ip.org/win7x86_x64.html) but I'm not sure if it is safe to use.

It asks for the default password to setup a local admin user and the domain name and everything, so if that data gets submitted anywhere this thing just isn't as safe to use as it is convenient.

Comment: You could use dummy values for those, and add them in offline to the output of the tool: e.g. PASSWORD, DOMAIN...

Comment: Yeah I'd much rather use an offline template of some sort

Comment: the tool runs on your computer, just like any other app, only this one you can see the source code and all activity, so i think it's safer than a pre-compiled tool with mystery meat guts. being "online" or "without https" doesn't mean anything significant since the code still runs on your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at [the sourcecode of the script](http://windowsafg.no-ip.org/scripts/win7x86x64_script.js) behind that website and see that it is completely client-sided and doesn't communicate with a server.

But just because the website delivered this script in that form to *me* does not mean that it will deliver the same script to *you*. Websites can easily deliver different content to different users. Also, there is no guarantee that this behaviour won't change tomorrow. But if the website is malicious, why would they target *you* but not *me*?

Another sore point is that the website doesn't seem to be available over https. That doesn't help a passive eavesdropper because, as I said, the file doesn't leave your computer. But an active MITM attacker could manipulate it in-transit to add a spying script. But that's a pretty unlikely scenario.

Bottom-line: It's *probably* safe enough for average people, but not safe enough for the paranoid. When you belong to the latter group and want to be completely sure, you could easily use it offline. Just safe the website to your local machine and open it from there. That way there is no way for the website to alter the script.

Comment: Well might as well save the page and steal the source then.

Comment: So what you're saying is, that I could basically run this with a network monitoring console window open in my browser load up the form with bad data, submit the data, and finally close the tab, and then see if any network requests are made; and if no network requests are made at all, I'm good, except if the browser remembers any one of the passwords that I typed in?